# Sorting first 20 highest values from a raw log file

Tags: python

From the log file present, I could able to sort out only the highest Response time (R.T), But I need to get first 20 highest values from it.

The log file which I am having has millions of line with different R.T( Response time) in it.

**Log file format**

Example:

```
00.00.00.000 - - [dd/mm/yyyy:hr:mm:se +0800] GET Url HTTP/1.1 200 dataconsumed (R.T) mainURL xxx/0.0 (x xxx 0.0; xx00) xx/00.00 (xx, xx xxx) /00.0.0000. xx/000.00
00.00.00.000 - - [dd/mm/yyyy:hr:mm:se +0800] GET Url HTTP/1.1 200 dataconsumed (R.T) mainURL xxx/0.0 (x xxx 0.0; xx00) xx/00.00 (xx, xx xxx) /00.0.0000. xx/000.00
00.00.00.000 - - [dd/mm/yyyy:hr:mm:se +0800] GET Url HTTP/1.1 200 dataconsumed (R.T) mainURL xxx/0.0 (x xxx 0.0; xx00) xx/00.00 (xx, xx xxx) /00.0.0000. xx/000.00
00.00.00.000 - - [dd/mm/yyyy:hr:mm:se +0800] GET Url HTTP/1.1 200 dataconsumed (R.T) mainURL xxx/0.0 (x xxx 0.0; xx00) xx/00.00 (xx, xx xxx) /00.0.0000. xx/000.00
00.00.00.000 - - [dd/mm/yyyy:hr:mm:se +0800] GET Url HTTP/1.1 200 dataconsumed (R.T) mainURL xxx/0.0 (x xxx 0.0; xx00) xx/00.00 (xx, xx xxx) /00.0.0000. xx/000.00
```

**Code 1:**

```
with open(r"file.txt","r") as f:
data = f.readlines()
# sort the data by response time descending using lambda as key
sorted_data = sorted(data,
                 key=lambda row: row.split()[10],
                 reverse=True)
```

**Output:(The log file which has high R.T)**

```
00.00.00.000 - - [dd/mm/yyyy:hr:mm:se +0800] GET Url HTTP/1.1 200 dataconsumed (R.T) mainURL xxx/0.0 (x xxx 0.0; xx00) xx/00.00 (xx, xx xxx) /00.0.0000. xx/000.00
```

**Code 2**

```
file = open(r"file.txt","r")
rts = []
for line in file:
line_array = line.split(" ")
rts.append(float(line_array[10]))
max_rt = max(rts)
print "Max R.T is :", max_rt
file.close()
```

**Output: Highest R.T**

Max R.T is: R.T

Help me!!!

To Find the 20 highest values from the log file.

Comment: Can't you just take `sorted_data[0:20]` as the lines you want?

Comment: I can't quite see what was wrong with Code 1

Comment: The 10th element is (R, T) how can you convert that to a float? Also I think you will need a regex to split the line as the timestamp has a space in it, which will cause the response time to be the 11th element, **if** there is a space in the timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this purpose you may want to use a heap. Python has a `heapq` module with an `nlargest` function for exactly this purpose. It will save you from having to store every line, which would be required for the sort and slice approach.

```
from heapq import nlargest

with open('naveen.log') as f:
    top20 = nlargest(20, f, key=lambda L: float(L.split()[10]))

for t in top20:
    print(t)
```

You could also use a `deque`, which can have its maximum length fixed. e.g. `collections.deque(maxlen=20)`

See my comment above for a request for clarification about how the data is formatted. Currently if you split a line (on spaces) it cuts the timestamp in half and the parameter you want is at the 11th index. If all your timestamps have the `+0800`, you can use the 11th index and you are sweet but if they dont then you may need to resort to more complex means to split the string (regular expressions).

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be as you are reading the log file line by line. Just keep sorted list of 20 entries. While reading new line just check if the last entry in the sorted list has response time greater than the new entry. If it has then remove the last entry and insert the new entry at appropriate place.

Hope this solves your problem.